# Why NSRDB API is not working with refering the Lat, Lon values inside the code?

Tags: python, api, pvlib, solar

I'm trying to fetch *TMY Solar Resource Data* from *NSRDB Database* using `Pvlib_get_psm3()` method. Using the below code. But getting error. The code that I AM Using:

```
NREL_API_KEY = '{{API_KEY'
lat1=st.number_input('Insert the Latitude:',value=52.4830986)
lon1=st.number_input('Insert the Longitude:',value=13.4920913)
metadata = pvlib.iotools.get_psm3(
    latitude=lat1, longitude=lon1,
    api_key=NREL_API_KEY,
    email='abc.xyz@gmail.com',
    names='tmy')
st.write(metadata)
```

Getting Error like this:

> HTTPError: ['No data available at the provided location', 'Data processing failure.']
> Traceback:
> File "C:\Users\amrit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 430, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**)
> File "C:\Users\amrit\Desktop\python\tracker\tilt_compare.py", line 148, in 
> metadata = pvlib.iotools.get_psm3(
> File "C:\Users\amrit\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pvlib\iotools\psm3.py", line 166, in get_psm3
> raise requests.HTTPError(errors, response=response)

But if I change the *Latitude* and *Longitude* values with Numerical (`Float`/`int`), then the code is working fine.

I'm not able to understand the issue here with the above code. Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

The geographical coverage for NSRDB PSM3 does not include the chosen point, which is in Europe. The warning that is returned also specifies this "No data available at the provided location".

For an overview of the geographical coverage of PSM3 see the below screen-shot:
[image]

For time series of solar irradiance in Europe, I would recommend that you look into PVGIS and CAMS Radiation (there exists pvlib functions for both). Alternatively, there is commercial data providers.